# SSRS DrillThrough Report to Excel From Main Report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, sql-server-data-tools

I am creating a drillthrough report in ssrs. I have two reports. First Report is pharmacyMain.
Here is the design picture.
[PharmacyMain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtNRb.png)
and second Report is PharmacyDetail. 
Here is the picture.[PharmacyDetail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOgRj.png)

What i have done. i set the Action of column "Status from PharmacyMain" to "Go to report" and added two parameters. Here is the picture.
[Action of pharmacyMain And parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ot9vz.png)

This works fine in ssrs.
But when i export this to excel and click on any value from column status. it shows this message.

Here is the picture
[Message in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1n3J.png). I am using ssrs 2012.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use "Go to report" as far as I know if you are planning to export to excel. The go to report action generates a URL internally that expects to be accessed from the report server.

Get round this in the past I have done the following.

Changed the Action to "Go to URL"

Set the URL to an expression such as the following example which also includes setting parameter values.

```
= Globals!ReportServerUrl
+ "?/myFolder/DetailReport" 
+ "&Period=" + cStr(Fields!Period.Value)
+ "&Id=" + cStr(Fields!Id.Value)
+ "&rc:Parameters=Collapsed"
```

The Globals!ReportServerUrl just gives you the base report server URL part.

Comment: I changed "go to report" to "Go To URL" And in expression put the code you wrote for me. But still same message is shown in Excel.

Comment: This will only work when the report is deployed, during development the ReportServerUrl will not be set